# Example of Banach algebra with non-zero anhillator ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is it possible for Banach algebras to have non-zero anhillator? In other words, does there exist a Banach algebra $A$ with an element $a$ such that $ab=0$ for all $b\in A$ ? Please mention few examples if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something; what about the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices (viewed as the algebra of bounded linear operators from $\mathbb{F}^2$ to itself) of the form
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
0 & 0 
\end{array}
\right), \qquad a,b\in \mathbb{F}.
$$
Then every element with $a=0$ annihilates every other element.

Comment: How about an example on field C?

Comment: @NewB: $\mathbb{F}$ can be any field you want...

Comment: My bad, I mistook it for cyclic field F2